# Re-process all Images in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, attachment, image-compression

I've got [a blog](http://www.rustyrambles.com/) that has the highest-resolution version of all its images embedded in the posts, rather than a thumbnail linking off to an image attachment page.

Can you tell me how I can re-process all embedded images so they're output as reduced size thumbnails that link off to their own attachment page (which is WordPress default settings)?

Am I right in thinking I can involve the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin in this?

Answer (score 1):

That was just about what I would suggest, it works wonders, but it will take longer depending on the amount of photos.

Another thing you can do is run the images through an optimizer before posting to speed up load times.

Comment: The Regenerate Thumbnails plugin unfortunately won't re-embed these photos, creating a thumbnail and linking that thumbnail to a separate image attachment page. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

And yes, separate to that I'll probably use [WP Smush.it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smushit/) for compression of these images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this plugin but there is a plugin called auto post thunbnail for wordpress. I have used it and it works great. You just press the generate button and wait till it generates thumbnails for all of your posts, if they have an image in them.

Comment: As explained I need a lot more than just re-generation of thumbnails.